# The "images.domains" configuration is deprecated. Please use "images.remotePatterns" configuration instead

Tags: next.js, cloudinary

I get the following warning in Next 14:

> The "images.domains" configuration is deprecated. Please use
> "images.remotePatterns" configuration instead.

My next.config.js has this

```
images: {
  domains: ['res.cloudinary.com'],
  remotePatterns: [
    {
      protocol: "https",
      hostname: "**",
    },
  ],
}
```

If I remove domains from there, I get error:

> `next/image`, hostname "res.cloudinary.com" is not configured under
> images in your `next.config.js`

Comment: Use [remotePatterns](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/components/image#remotepatterns)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

In Next.js Version 14, domains configuration has been deprecated in favour of remotePatterns. This can be defined in the next.config.js file.

Here is a reference as per the Next.js docs: [remotePatterns](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/components/image#remotepatterns)

In your snippet, after you remove the domains configuration as you have described, it seems that you have mixed up your values in remotePatterns configuration, because you have set the hostname value to the wildcard `'**'` instead of the actual hostname `'res.cloudinary.com'`, thus the error **hostname "res.cloudinary.com" is not configured.**

Try to do this instead:

```html
 images: {
    remotePatterns: [
      {
        protocol: 'https',
        hostname: 'res.cloudinary.com',
        pathname: '**',
      },
    ],
  },
```

Comment: If I have multiple links, do I need to specify the protocol and pathname for all the hostnames individually on next.config.mjs?

`remotePatterns: [
  {
    protocol: 'https',
    hostname: 'uploadthing.com',
    pathname: '**',
  },
  {
    protocol: 'https',
    hostname: 'img.clerk.com',
    pathname: '**',
  },
  {
    protocol: 'https',
    hostname: 'files.stripe.com',
    pathname: '**',
  },
],`

Is there a more efficient way to implement this?

Answer (score 1):

**Here is the solution.**
I am using Google Provider Next-Auth (authjs’s new name).
In the hostname add your URL.
For more details, [visit Next/image un-configured Host](https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/next-image-unconfigured-host).

```
images: {
    remotePatterns: [
      {
        protocol: 'https',
        hostname: 'lh3.googleusercontent.com',
        port: '',
        pathname: '/**',
      },
    ],
```